# Is there a better way of adding values of the same array index in laravel using foreach that is memory efficient?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code to achieve:
The values of $categoryRatings are the following arrays:

```
$categoryRatings = array:2 [
   2 => array:2 [
     1 => 50.0
     2 => 35.0
   ]
   3 => array:2 [
     1 => 55.0
     2 => 45.0
   ]
 ]


$indexes = [];
    foreach ($categoryRatings as $categoryRating) {

        foreach ($categoryRating as $key => $value) {

            foreach ($categories as $category) {

                if ($category->id == $key) {

                    $indexes[$category->id] = isset($indexes[$category->id]) ? ($indexes[$category->id] + $value) : $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $overAllCategoryRating = [];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $overAllCategoryRating[$category->id] = $indexes[$category->id]/sizeof($categoryRatings);
    }
```

And the output of $overallCategoryRating is equal to:

```
array:2 [
  1 => 52.5
  2 => 40.0
]
```

The $categories here is a collection where I used the id as key so that I can assign the results to its key for use in my front end.

Is there some ways to optimized this code for memory efficient since when large data is computed it won't get results fast because of many foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$first = collect($categoryRatings)->avg(1) // Result: 52.5
$second = collect($categoryRatings)->avg(2) // Result: 40.0
```

Comment: Hi Javier, thanks for your answer its correct. How about this the same thing just 3 dimensional array this time with some string in array values so it's a mix of string and numeric values.
array:2 [
  2 => array:3 [
    1 => array:2 [
      1 => 50.0
      2 => 50.0
    ]
    2 => array:1 [
      3 => 35.0
    ]
    3 => array:1 [
      4 => "in-progress"
    ]
  ]
  3 => array:3 [
    1 => array:2 [
      1 => 60.0
      2 => 50.0
    ]
    2 => array:1 [
      3 => 45.0
    ]
    3 => array:1 [
      4 => "in-progress"
    ]
  ]
]